# Что значит -1 как результат indexOf()?

Tags: jquery, javascript

не могу понять следующий код

```
$(function(){  
    $("#search").keyup(function(){  
        var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();  
        $(".names li").hide();  
        $(".names li").each(function(){  
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

            if(text.indexOf(val) != -1) {  
                $(this).show();  
            }  
        });  
    });  
});
```

да понимаю, что по нажатию кнопки, он приводит введенное значение в нижний регистр, все `li` скрывает и потом для каждого `li` сравнивает `indexOf` и показывает  если ок.

не могу понять что значит `-1` в условии

```
 if(text.indexOf(val) != -1)
```

то есть, `indexOf` ('строка', индекс). в данном случае `-1` - это первый символ с конца? или нет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`indexOf` возвращает -1, если подстрока в строке не найдена

Comment: то есть если if(text.indexOf (val) == -1 ) не найдено , могу делать alert('No results'). во только из-за того что наверно событие keyup, у меня сообщение всегда срабатывает после ввода буквы. не подскажите как правильно сделать если совпадений нет?

Comment: лучше добавить айтем li с сообщением No results и своим стилем (другим цветом, например) и показывать его, если ничего не нашли

Comment: if(text.indexOf(val) != -1) {  
                $(this).show();  
            } else {
$('.result').text('Совпадений не найдено')
} после такого, выводит  и то и другое

http://clip2net.com/s/6UFayV

Comment: Потому-что у вас else в цикле. Покажите это сообщение до цикла, а в случае найденного совпадения спрячьте. Либо используйте флаг, указывающий на то что что-то нашли.  и это... пользуйтесь сервисом jsfiddle чтобы показать что не работает, скриншот почти не о чем не говорит.

Comment: да извиняюсь ))) http://jsfiddle.net/V84rH/ вот попробовала, но все же где-то явно я туплю. не могу сообразить чета. не всегда срабатывает правильно((

Answer (score 2):

```
text.indexOf(val)
```

Елси подстрока **val** найдена в строке **text**, то возвращает индекс подстроки (от 0 и больше). Иначе: **-1**